# MySQL Stored Procedure syntax error with table variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this MySQL query to create a stored procedure:

```
Delimiter //;
Create Procedure addUser(
    IN facebookId varchar(20), 
        IN name varchar(50), 
        In accessToken varchar(100), 
        in expires float)
Begin
    Declare invitingUsers Table(Id varchar(20));

        Insert Into Users 
        (`Facebook_Id`,`Name`,`Access_Token`,`Expired`) Values (facebookId,name,accessToken,expires);

        Select Inviting_Id 
        From Invited_Users
        Where Invited_Id = facebookId
        Into invitingUsers;

        Update Table Users 
        Set Credit = Credit + 1 
        Where Facebook_Id In (Select Id From invitingUsers);
End//
```

but I'm keep getting this error - can't understand why:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table(Id varchar(20)); Insert Into Users (`Facebook' at line 7
```

Comment: apparently mySql doesn't use table variable. the solution was to create a temp table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Change #1

`Delimiter //;` to `Delimiter //`

## Change #2

Create a Temp Table in Memory

## Change #3

Changed

```
Select Inviting_Id 
From Invited_Users
Where Invited_Id = facebookId
Into invitingUsers;
```

into

```
INSERT INTO invitingUsers          
Select Inviting_Id From Invited_Users
Where Invited_Id = facebookId;
```

With these changes I give you this:

```
Delimiter //
Create Procedure addUser(
    IN facebookId varchar(20), 
        IN name varchar(50), 
        In accessToken varchar(100), 
        in expires float)
Begin
        Declare invitingUsers Table(Id varchar(20));
        
        Create temporary table if not exists invitingUsers
        (Id varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=MEMORY;

        Insert Into Users 
        (`Facebook_Id`,`Name`,`Access_Token`,`Expired`)
        Values (facebookId,name,accessToken,expires);

        INSERT INTO invitingUsers          
        Select Inviting_Id From Invited_Users
        Where Invited_Id = facebookId;
        
        Update Table Users 
        Set Credit = Credit + 1 
        Where Facebook_Id In (Select Id From invitingUsers);
End//
Delimiter ;
```

Give it a Try !!!